# Select Previous Record in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here's the case: I have one table `myTable` which contains 3 columns:

- `ID` `int, identity`
- `Group` `varchar(2), not null`
- `value` `decimal(18,0), not null`

Table looks like this:

```
ID  GROUP   VALUE   Prev_Value  Result
------------------------------------------
1   A       20      0           20
2   A       30      20          10
3   A       35      30          5
4   B       100     0           100
5   B       150     100         50
6   B       300     200         100
7   C       40      0           40
8   C       60      40          20
9   A       50      35          15
10  A       70      50          20
```

`Prev_Value` and `Result` columns should be custom columns. I need to make it on view. Anyone can help? please... Thank  you so much.

Comment: Can you explain "custom field"

Comment: I think he means computed field.

Comment: Please explain the rules you use to generate Prev_Value and Result. I see no pattern.

Comment: prev_value would take the previous value of the record. if you see on record number 2. prev_value is 20. taken from record number 1. ff. Based on 'Group' field. The 'Result' field, 'value' - 'prev_value'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gist of what you need to do here is to join the table to itself, where part of the join condition is that the value column of the joined copy of the table is less than value column of the original. Then you can group by the columns from the original table and select the max value from the joined table to get your results:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.[Group], t1.Value
     , coalesce(MAX(t2.Value),0) As Prev_Value
     , t1.Value - coalesce(MAX(t2.Value),0) As Result
FROM MyTable t1
LEFT JOIN MyTable t2 ON t2.[Group] = t1.[Group] and t2.Value < t1.Value
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.[Group], t1.Value
```

Once you can update to Sql Server 2012 you'll also be able to take advantage of the [new LAG keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much... You r the man!! But if run it on sql 2012.. will work?